# Unable to npm install -g npm@7.6.2 after React asked for npm update

Tags: reactjs, npm

Hello I have some issue with isntalling globally npm packages.

This is Error:

```
npm ERR! syscall lstat
npm ERR! path /home/guzlej/.npm-global/lib
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/home/guzlej/.npm-global/lib'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/guzlej/.npm/_logs/2021-03-11T07_28_49_216Z-debug.log
```

thank you for any help, I had this problem with installing AdonisJS too but still didn't resolve it and not even sure how

Comment: Try : npm install [package_name] -g —force. And see if it installs

Comment: Hello, Jad thank you for your answer. I've have tried your way and I got the same output